# Why use Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF instead of drand()

Tags: swift, random, cgfloat

I'm new to Swift and just saw this code used to generate a random angle degree in a tutorial.

```
func random() ->CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func random(#min: CGFloat, max:CGFloat) ->CGFloat{
    return random()*(max-min)+min
}
```

I'm wondering is the line  `return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)` generates a random float number between 0 and 1.0? Then why cannot just use drand()? Any difference between the two functions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drand48()` is fine for lots of applications, but is insecure (in other words predictable). `arc4random()` while [not perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) was designed with security in mind.

I think Apple pushes people to `arc4random()` because of that. So, to answer your question: if you are generating random numbers to simulate something, `drand48` should be fine, but if you are generating random numbers to protect something, then use `arc4random()` (or something even more secure like `SecRandomCopyBytes()`).

---

From ONLamp's [Secure Programming Techniques](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/excerpt/PUIS3_chap16/index4.html?page=2):

> #### drand48( ), lrand48( ), and mrand48( )
>
> The drand48( ) function is one of many functions that make up the System V random number generator. According to the Solaris documentation, the algorithm uses "the well-known linear congruential algorithm and 48-bit integer arithmetic." The function drand48( ) returns a double-precision number that is greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0, while the lrand48( ) and mrand48( ) functions return random numbers within a specified integer range. As with random( ), these functions provide excellent random numbers for simulations and games, but should not be used for security-related applications such as picking cryptographic keys or simulating one-time pads; linear congruential algorithms are too easy to break.