# Calculate random X and Y based on center point with min and max offset

Tags: swift

[image]

Above you see my `UIView` which is a rectangle with a black border. In the middle is the center (red dot) and furthermore, 2 circles.

My goal is to generate a random X and Y point with a minimum and maximum offset based on the center of the `UIView`. The green circle gives away the minimum X and Y positions, while the red outer circle indicates the maximum X and Y positions. My goal is to generate an X and Y value between those two circles.

Lets say I have a `UIView` which size is 100,100 and I want to get a random X and Y value with a minimum offset which is 80% of the view (green circle) and a maximum offset of 120% (red circle).

My bad attempt to generate a random X value:

```
var finalX = CGFloat.random(lower: heightUIView *  0.8, heightUIView * 1.2)

let toDown = Int.random(lower: 0, 1) == 0 ? true : false
if !toDown {
    finalX = -finalX
}
```

This would never generate a good X value since these values can not be 0 (while that could be an option, looking at the picture)

Comment: What's the state of your knowledge of basic geometry? Do you know about polar coordinates?

Comment: @matt no, I really do not have any clue :(. I am already searching and I found out about geometry and all. Maybe that is the key

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system So you need a random theta between zero and 2 pi, and you need a random r between the smaller radius and larger radius. Now convert that to cartesian coordinates, round to integer values, and offset the result by the coordinates of the center. Done.

Comment: Note that  `? true : false` is redundant. `let toDown = Int.random(lower: 0, 1) == 0`

Comment: Are you trying to perform this calculation many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general formula to get a random number between `min` and `max` is:

```
let rand = arc4random_uniform(max - min) + min
```

But in your case, if you do that for an `x` and `y` value, you will not get values between the green and red circles. You will get values in boxes that contain the circles.

To get a random point between the two circles you need something along these lines:

```
let greenRadius = 4 // whatever the radius of the green circle is
let redRadius = 10 // whatever the radius of the red circle is
let randRadius = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(redRadius - greenRadius)) + UInt32(greenRadius))
let randAngle = Double(arc4random_uniform(360)) / 180 * Double.pi
let x = cos(randAngle) * randRadius
let y = sin(randAngle) * randRadius
```

That will give you an `x` and `y` around a center of 0, 0. Add those to your actual center point to get your final values.

Comment: Perhaps not important, but note that this will not result in a uniform distribution (with respect to the area).

Comment: @MartinR Can you clarify please? It's a random angle and random radius within the given area.

Comment: See for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html. Points near the outer radius are less likely than points near the inner radius.

Comment: @MartinR Right. Since points between two angles are further apart with greater radius.

Comment: Interesting. At first glance it seems like this *should* give a uniform distribution, but I see now why it doesn't. I didn't quite understand the solution to a uniform distribution though. Martin, care to post a solution that DOES yield a uniform distribution?

Comment: Oh, I see. `x=sqrt(r) *cos(theta)` `y=sqrt(r) *sin(theta)`. Makes sense.

Comment: Yea I ran some tests and it looks like the inner circle has more point in it than the outer circle: https://ibb.co/g4g4rc, but I am happy, I would never spawn so many points anyway :)

Comment: Hmm. Won't your angle code generate angles that are in discrete 1-degree steps since you're using an integer random value from 0-259 to calculate theta

Comment: @DuncanC I was waiting for that to come up. Yeah, I did that just because it was easier as I was typing out the code into the answer. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to calculate the values with more precision.

Comment: Martin's answer takes care of that, since he uses `arc4random())/(CGFloat(UInt32.max)` * scale in his calculations.

Comment: Don't I remember seeing new floating point random functions in Swift 4? Those would be easier still.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a random point with uniform distribution in the annulus
(with respect to area measure) you need to

- Compute a uniformly distributed angle φ in the range [0, 2π),
- Compute a uniformly distributed radius r in the range [r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, r<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>],
- Compute the point P = (sqrt(r) * cos(φ), sqrt(r) * sin(φ)).

(From [Disk Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) on Wolfram
Mathworld.)

Code example:

```
let r1: CGFloat = 2  // inner radius
let r2: CGFloat = 10 // outer radius

let phi = CGFloat(arc4random())/(CGFloat(UInt32.max) + 1) * 2 * .pi
let rSquared = (CGFloat(arc4random())/CGFloat(UInt32.max) * (r2 * r2 - r1 * r1) + r1 * r1)
let r = rSquared.squareRoot()

let randomPoint = CGPoint(x: r * cos(phi), y: r * sin(phi))
```

Comment: Wauw!! This is amazing, I just accepted rmaddys answer but I will use this one :)

Comment: @J.Doe If you think this answer is better, you should accept it over mine. Don't worry, I won't be offended. :)

Comment: You passed up a chance to use the new `Double` random number functions in Swift 4 (`drand48()`)

Comment: @DuncanC: [`drand48`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) is not new at all, and not necessarily better than `arc4random`, compare [Why use Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF instead of drand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490662/why-use-floatarc4random-0xffffffff-instead-of-drand). In particular, it has to be seeded. – Perhaps you were thinking of [SE-0202 Random Unification](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md)? That is not yet implemented in Swift 4.1, it is currently under review.

Comment: I should have known `drand48()` was a C math library function.