# Swift randomFloat issue: '4294967295' is not exactly representable as 'Float'

Tags: swift, swift5

When generating a random CGFloat, I use the following code. [Some explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490662/why-use-floatarc4random-0xffffffff-instead-of-drand)

```
extension CGFloat{
     static func randomFloat(from:CGFloat, to:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
          let randomValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
          return randomValue * (to - from ) + from
      } 
}
```

It used to be OK. Works fine now.

There is a warning, after I upgraded to Swift 5.

> '4294967295' is not exactly representable as 'Float'; it becomes '4294967296'

to the line of code

```
let randomValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest solution: abandon your code and just call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/2994408-random.

Comment: Not just simpler, but better. Don't overcomplicate things by reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Alexander Well, there's even more than that. The whole point of `random(in:)` is that `arc4random` is deprecated.

Comment: Oh really? I thought it was the low-level API for accessing the random device that underpins the new random implementation

Comment: Look at minute 27 of https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/401

Answer (score 12):

As you know `Float` has only 24-bits of significand, so 32-bit value 0xFFFFFFFF would be truncated. So, Swift is warning to you that `Float` cannot represent the value `0xFFFFFFFF` precisely.

The short fix would be something like this:

```
let randomValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(0xFFFFFFFF))
```

With using `Float.init` explicitly, Swift would not generate such warnings.

---

But the preferred way would be using `random(in:)` method as suggested in matt's answer:

```
return CGFloat(Float.random(in: from...to))
```

or simply:

```
return CGFloat.random(in: from...to)
```